# want someone to do my homework for me

Tags: python-3.x

```
# Change this program to output each letter of the text entered on a separate line
# with space in front of each letter, increasing to the right for each letter.
# For example, 'Python' input should output:
# P
#  y
#   t
#    h
#     o
#      n

text = input('Enter text: ')
for letter in text:
    print(letter)
```

I already tried to look online for the solution, there are none.
This code is for homework but i cant figure it out help wold be appreciated

Comment: Please read [Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#strings), especially String part.

Comment: Also, telling people that you want them to do your homework for you is not a good way to get the results you want

Comment: The most hilarious title on all of SO

Answer (score 4):

As you haven't told us what you have tried to do so far, or what you have tried to learn to figure it out, I'm not going to post the Python code. Instead, lets think about what the program should be doing. Your assignment statement gives a broad overview, but as a programmer you need to take this overview and turn it into a set of smaller instructions. These smaller steps do not have to be in code. They can be in whatever form you like, even plain english.

For functional analysis (which is what you are doing for this problem) start with the inputs and outputs then fill in the stuff in-between.

- 1) Input: a string
- X) Output: multiple lines with a single character and whitespace

Now how do you want to get from 1 to X. You already have the code to loop through each letter and print it, but you are missing two things to get to your required output.

- A) way to place a string on a new line
- B) way to add whitespace to a string

I'll give you a couple of hints. A) is something that is extremely common in almost any programming language. In fact, it is done the exact same way is any language that you are likely to use. Another hint. Your final output will be a single string that spans multiple lines. Ask yourself how a word processor or text editor gives works with blank lines.

B is a little more tricky, as there are a couple of nifty Python tricks that makes it simpler to do than in other languages. I'm guessing that you already know what happens when you add two numbers together such as `3 + 5`. But what happens when you add two strings together such as `"foo" + "bar"`. Notice how the behavior for adding numbers with the `+` operator is completely different than the behavior is for adding strings together with the same operator? That difference in behavior applies to other common operators as well. Play around with the other three common mathematical operators on both string and numbers to see what happens

Comment: Thanks for not writing the code. We can only hope your attempt at teaching is attended to.